# Perl: Modify variable passed as param to subroutine

Tags: perl, parameters, pass-by-reference, subroutine

I need to modify a variable inside a routine, so it keeps the changes after leaving the routine. Here's an example:

```
$text = "hello";
&convert_to_uppercase($text);
print $text;
```

I want to see "HELLO" on the screen, not "hello".

The routine would be:

```
sub convert_to_uppercase($text){
  <something like $text = uc($text);>
}
```

I know how to do it in PHP, but it seems that the parameters are not changed the same way. And, I've been searching everywhere and I couldn't find a concrete answer.

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063638/if-perl-is-call-by-reference-why-does-this-happen

Comment: Thanks a lot! My new question is: why ($x1, $y1) = @_;? Would it be the same if i did: **$x1 = $_[0]; $y1 = $_[1];**? Please consider I'm really new to Perl, and thanks for your patience!

Comment: Yes it is. `($x1, $y1) = @_;` is a shortcut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *really* shouldn't use an ampersand `&` when calling a Perl subroutine. It is necessary only when treating the code as a data item, for instance when taking a reference, like `\&convert_to_uppercase`. Using it in a call hasn't been necessary since version 4 of Perl 5, and it does some arcane things that you probably don't want.

It is unusual for subroutines to modify their parameters, but the elements of `@_` are aliases of the actual parameters so you can do what you ask by modifying that array.

If you write your subroutine like this

```
sub convert_to_uppercase {
    $_[0] = uc $_[0];
}
```

then it will do what you ask. But it is generally best to *return* the modified value so that the decision on whether to overwrite the original value can be taken by the calling code. For instance, if I have

```
sub upper_case {
    uc shift;
}
```

then it can be called *either* as

```
my $text = "hello"; 
$text = upper_case($text);
print $text;
```

which does as you require, and modifies `$text`; or as

```
my $text = "hello";
print upper_case($text);
```

which leaves `$text` unchanged, but returns the altered value.

Comment: Great! One more thing: isn't it necessary to declare the routine signature? I see you do **sub convert_to_uppercase{}** instead of **sub convert_to_uppercase($text){}** but when you call it, you do **convert_to_uppercase($text)**.
Another thing, I used the **&** because I didn't know I shouldn't, I'm really new to Perl. What I'm doing is a validation from user input, so I want to uppercase the input from the user (I'll check it later too), and return a 1 or a 0 if valid or not, that's why I don't use the the return to do this.
You were really helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @gonfer, no. Sub signatures have only been added as a core Perl feature since Perl 5.20 (which came out a few months ago), and only experimentally. (Though there are several implementations of signatures available as extension modules of varying levels of stability.)

Answer (score 6):

Passing a reference and modifying the original variable inside the subroutine would be done like this:

```
$text = 'hello';
convert_to_uppercase(\$text);  #notice the \ before $text
print $text;

sub convert_to_uppercase {       #perl doesn't specify arguments here

    ### arguments will be in @_, so @_ is now a list like ('hello') 
    my $ref = shift;             #$ref is NOT 'hello'. it's '$text'

    ### add some output so you can see what's going on:
    print 'Variable $ref is: ', $ref, " \n";  #will print some hex number like SCALAR(0xad1d2)
    print 'Variable ${$ref} is: ', ${$ref}, " \n"; #will print 'hello'

    # Now do what this function is supposed to do:
    ${$ref} = uc ${$ref};  #it's modifying the original variable, not a copy of it
}
```

The other way is to create a return value inside the subroutine and modify the variable outside of the subroutine:

```
$text = 'hello';
$text = convert_to_uppercase($text);  #there's no \ this time
print $text;

sub convert_to_uppercase {
    # @_ contains 'hello'
    my $input = shift;    #$input is 'hello'
    return uc $input;    #returns 'HELLO'
}
```

But the convert_to_uppercase routine seems redundant because that's what uc does. Skip all of that and just do this:

```
$text = 'hello';
$text = uc $text;
```

Comment: Hello, you cleared out all my doubts! As I replied the other guy, I'm validating a key entered by the user. I want to uppercase it AND validate it, and leave it in upper case for future checks. If it's valid, I'll return 1, otherwise 0. A simple **uc** would be easier, but I wanted to do all this inside a single routine. Thanks a lot to you too. I'm amused by the quality and speed of the replies here.

Comment: One moe thing now I read you reply again: modifying the @_, the variable is changed outside the routine, but is it necessary to pass it with the \ when calling the subroutine? This way, the $ref is an actual reference to the variable, and you de-reference it with the {}. The use of {} is only when you pass the parameter with the \? Thanks!

Comment: It's worth telling that you can use `convert_to_uppercase($text);` (without "\" before the subroutine parameter) instead of `convert_to_uppercase(\$text);` by adding "\" before `shift`: `my $ref = \shift;`