# Sed - replace words

Tags: sed

I have a problem with replacing string.

```
|Stm=2|Seq=2|Num=2|Svc=101|MsgSize(514)=514|MsgType=556|SymbolIndex=16631
```

I want to find occurrence of `Svc` till `|` appears and swap place with `Stm` till `|` appears.

My attempts went to replacing characters and this is not my goal.

Comment: sorry for my english - swaping - not replacing

Comment: you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40422418/edit) your question too :) do add expected output for clarity as well as add the command you tried

Comment: awk is better than sed for handling columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 
      '{a=b=0;
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a=$i~/^Stm=/?i:a;b=$i~/^Svc=/?i:b}
        t=$a;$a=$b;$b=t}7' file
```

outputs:

```
|Svc=101|Seq=2|Num=2|Stm=2|MsgSize(514)=514|MsgType=556|SymbolIndex=16631
```

- the code exchange the column of `Stm..` and `Svc..`, no matter which one   comes first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use capture groups and backreferences in a string substition.

The below will swap the 2:

`echo '|Stm=2|Seq=2|Num=2|Svc=101|MsgSize(514)=514|MsgType=556|SymbolIndex=16631' | sed 's/\(Stm.*|\)\(.*\)\(Svc.*|\)/\3\2\1/'`

As pointed out in the comment from @Kent, this will not work if the strings were not in that order.

Comment: what if `Svc` comes first

Comment: you have got a typo, you have escaped `|` which shouldn't have been as you are using BRE

Comment: Removed the unneeded `|` based on your comment @Sundeep

Answer (score 0):

If `perl` solution is okay, assumes only one column matches each for search terms

```
$ cat ip.txt 
|Stm=2|Seq=2|Num=2|Svc=101|MsgSize(514)=514|MsgType=556|SymbolIndex=16631

$ perl -F'\|' -lane '
@i = grep { $F[$_] =~ /Svc|Stm/ } 0..$#F;
$t=$F[$i[0]]; $F[$i[0]]=$F[$i[1]]; $F[$i[1]]=$t;
print join "|", @F;
' ip.txt
|Svc=101|Seq=2|Num=2|Stm=2|MsgSize(514)=514|MsgType=556|SymbolIndex=16631
```

- `-F'\|' -lane` split input line on `|`, see also [Perl flags -pe, -pi, -p, -w, -d, -i, -t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302025/perl-flags-pe-pi-p-w-d-i-t)
- `@i = grep { $F[$_] =~ /Svc|Stm/ } 0..$#F` get index of columns matching `Svc` and `Stm`
- `$t=$F[$i[0]]; $F[$i[0]]=$F[$i[1]]; $F[$i[1]]=$t` swap the two columns

  - Or use `($F[$i[0]], $F[$i[1]]) = ($F[$i[1]], $F[$i[0]]);` courtesy [How can I swap two Perl variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606192/how-can-i-swap-two-perl-variables-without-using-the-third)
- `print join "|", @F` print the modified array